# How to write matrices from matlab to .xlsx with special formatting tables

Tags: matlab, matrix, formatting, export, export-to-excel

I have one problem with exporting matrices from Matlab to Excel. This is not a problem, but I need some formatting. 
I made matrices A and B and I printed them to .xlsx document.

```
filename = 'example.xlsx'; 
A;
sheet = 1;                 
xlRange = 'A9';           
xlswrite(filename,A,sheet,xlRange)  

B;
xlRange2= 'B9';
xlswrite(filename,B,sheet,xlRange2)
```

And i get the example.xlsx file with this formating:

```
400 4.56
500 5.12
600 6.76
700 7.98
800 8.21
900 9.21
1000 10.12
1100 11.23
1200 12.43
1300 13.89
1400 14.54
1500 15.21
1600 16.23
1700 17.53
```

I need this kind of formating:

```
400 4.56

500 5.12
600 6.76
700 7.98
800 8.21
900 9.21

1000 10.12
 100 11.23
 200 12.43
 300 13.89
 400 14.54

 500 15.21
 600 16.23
 700 17.53
```

Steps are on 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500... How to put one empty row and how to make this kind of formating?

Comment: Converting your data to a cell, you could insert rows with empty elements.

Comment: OK. How to do that and how to get format that is wanted? Example?

Comment: Could you try `M={400 4.56;500 5.12;[] [];600 6.76;700 7.98};xlswrite('a.xlsx',M)` or `M={400 4.56;500 5.12;'' '';600 6.76;700 7.98};xlswrite('b.xlsx',M)`. I don't have excel installed so I can't try, but at least one of these creates an empty row.

Comment: Both are working but I have a lot of data in both matrices. I cant just do it this way.

Comment: I wrote an answer. Just noticed your example has the gap before 500 in one case and after 500 in the other. If my answer provides the wrong behaviour, you have to replace the `@gt` with `@ge`

Comment: It is working with '@ge'. And this is ok but how to get the :
'1000 10.12
 100 11.23
 200 12.43
 300 13.89
 400 14.54

 500 15.21
 600 16.23
 700 17.53'

look at the example format that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code provides the cell as required for xlswrite:

```
M=[400 4.56
500 5.12
600 6.76
700 7.98
800 8.21
900 9.21
1000 10.12
1100 11.23
1200 12.43
1300 13.89
1400 14.54
1500 15.21
1600 16.23
1700 17.53
900 9.21
1000 10.12
1100 11.23
1200 12.43
1300 13.89
1400 14.54
1500 15.21
1600 16.23
1700 17.53];
gaps=[500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500];
%calculates a group indx. 0 is below first gap, 1 between first and second etc..
group=sum(bsxfun(@ge,M(:,1),gaps),2);
%whenever group increases a line must be jumped, calculate indices
index=cumsum(ones(size(M,1),1)+[0;diff(group)>0]);
%allocate empty cell
X=cell(max(index),size(M,2));
%fill data
X(index,:)=num2cell(M);
xlswrite('a.xlsx',X)
```